# Make button 'login as' in Djang for admin

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-admin

Please someone tell me how I can create button in admin.py that admin can type username and whit that button login like that user.

Answer (score 0):

This is called *impersonating*, and you can for example use [**`django-impersonate`** [pypi]](https://pypi.org/project/django-impersonate/) for this.

You can install `django-impersonate` with the package manager of your virtual environment, for example with `pip3`:

```
pip3 install django-impersonate
```

Next you need to add the `impersonate` app to the [**`INSTALLED_APPS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#installed-apps), and add the [**`MIDDLEWARE`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#middleware):

```
# settings.py

# …

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …,
    'impersonate'
]

# …

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # …
    'impersonate.middleware.ImpersonateMiddleware'
]

# …
```

Then in the root `urls.py` file, you can add the impersonate urls:

```
# project/urls.py

from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # …,
    path('impersonate/', include('impersonate.urls')),
)
```

Then when you are an admin urser, you can impersonate a person with a given id by visiting:

```
/impersonate/user-id/
```

where you substitute *`user-id`* with the user id.

You can add a link to the users to impersonate that user with:

```
# appname/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html

User = get_user_model()

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    list_display = BaseUserAdmin.list_display
    list_display += ('show_impersonate_link',)

    def show_impersonate_link(self, obj):
        url = reverse(impersonate-start, args=[obj.pk])
        return format_html(
            f'impersonate'
        )
    show_impersonate_link.short_description = 'impersonate'


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```